# How to create thread safe reference wrapper?

Tags: c++, concurrency, locking, mutex

I'm new to C++ and would like to understand how to create a reference wrapper over `OwnerRef`, which holds the lock and releases it on destruction.

```
template <typename T, class Mutex = twist::ed::stdlike::mutex>
class Mutexed {
  // How to define my own OwnerRef?
  using OwnerRef = T*;

 public:
  // https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/
  template <typename... Args>
  explicit Mutexed(Args&&... args)
      : object_(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
  }

  OwnerRef Acquire() {
    std::lock_guard guard(mutex_);
    return &object_;
  }

 private:
  T object_;
  Mutex mutex_;  // Guards access to object_
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template <typename T>
auto Acquire(Mutexed<T>& object) {
  return object.Acquire();
}
```

The problem with this code is that `Acquire()` will hold the mutex only till it returns (due to the RAII behavior of std::lock_guard). It does not protect accessing the `OwnerRef` after we got it from `Acquire()`.

I would like to support the following usage

```
 * Mutexed<std::vector<Apple>> apples;
 *
 * {
 *   auto owner_ref = apples->Acquire();
 *   owner_ref->push_back(Apple{});
 * }  // <- release ownership
 *
 */
```

created a solution

```
  class OwnerRef {
   public:
    OwnerRef(T* obj, Mutex& lock)
        : m_obj(obj),
          guard(lock) {
    }

    T* operator->() {
      return m_obj;
    }

   private:
    T* m_obj;
    std::lock_guard<Mutex> guard;
  };
```

Comment: You need to create class that contains `unique_lock` and pointer to native data, with operations like `*` and `->` that access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement an `OwnerRef` that:

1. Saves a pointer to the underlying object ***and its mutex (see below)***.
2. Overloads `*` and `->` operators, and uses the saved pointer to implement them, returning a pointer to the underlying object.
3. Has a deleted copy constructor and assignment operator. It is a move-only object. The move constructor transfers the pointer to the moved-to object. The moved-from object's pointer is set to null, and in that condition the `*` and `->` overloads will throw an exception. You may or may not need to implement a move-assignment operator, depending on your requirements. The factory that returns a new `OwnerRef` must construct it, as a prvalue, and return it, in order to comply with these restrictions.
4. A simple `lock_guard` will not work here. A mutex must be kept separately, together with the locked object. The same pointer is used to `lock()` the mutex when your `OwnerRef` is constructed. The destructor for an `OwnerRef` with a non-null pointer will release the mutex lock. It's possible that you can take a shortcut and rely on `lock_guard`'s own move-only semantics, here. But this won't help you if you eventually figure out that you need to make things a bit more complicated (see below).

Putting this all together: the end result will be a guaranteed single instance of a non-moved from `OwnerRef` that has the underlying mutex locked, until it's destroyed.

It's possible to avoid some work by not implementing move semantics, and try to make everything work using mandatory copy-elision that does not require a movable/copyable object. But it's not too much extra work, and this will make things versatile.

A word of caution: it's very easy to deadlock yourself, here, unless you make sure that your `OwnerRef`s are very, very short lived. It's very easy to grab an `OwnerRef` at the beginning of a function, and, as part of doing business, the function calls other functions which want an `OwnerRef` of their own.

After the first couple of times you'll deal with this, you might want to go back and revisit everything, and make it work as long as all `OwnerRef`s are from the same execution thread. You can't rely on a simple `lock_guard`, any more.

Comment: could you please provide a code sample?

Comment: The code should be, pretty much, spelled out as per my description: pointer member, constructor, destructor, move constructor, and the three operator overloads: `*`, `=>`, `=` (move). Is there something ***specific*** that's unclear that I can help explain? Are you familiar with all these C++ concepts?

Comment: found a solution and updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Reference can't be safe across threads. In fact most often, references that outlive their creation context are dangling references. So a **thread safe reference wrapper** is simply a misnomer.
You may consider using some **smart pointer** instead or use the `std::promise`, `std::future` pairs or similar types.